# how to find whether i am using infopath form or sharepoint list form in SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, powershell, infopath

I am keen in learning more on infopath. How to know, whether we are using custom infopath form or sharepoint list form. Is there any way to find which one we are using for creating items on the list ot library. Environment SP2010. Under subsite, we had library, lists and reusable workflow associated with site. I want to is there any custom infopath exist on my subsite or not. please suggest me how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

- **Method #1**. This is fairly straightforward, you just need the proper permissions on the list:

  - Navigate to the list you want to determine the form type
  - Click on the Library or List tab while in the default view.  This will display the list level commands available to you.
  - Click on library settings.  It should be on the far right of the list tab ribbon.  If you have sufficient privileges to edit the 
    settings the ribbon button will not be disabled.
  - Click on the ‘Form Settings’ link.
  - if the option ‘Use the default form’ is selected, your list is **not** using a custom InfoPath form.  Alternatively, if ‘Use a custom form created in InfoPath’ is selected, your list is using InfoPath.
- **Method 2**: look at the URL for when you create a new list item.  If the url contains ‘newifs.aspx?’ followed by the URL query segment, the list is using InfoPath as a custom form.  If not, it is using the out of the box form.

**Note**:  Libraries cannot use InfoPath to customize the new, edit or display forms.  They only use the out of the box forms.  But you can have a library that contains InfoPath forms as the primary content type.  This is called a form library.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL contains NewForm.aspx,DispForm.aspx,EditForm.aspx, you are using list forms

If the URL contains newifs.aspx,displayifs.aspx,editifs.aspx, you are using infopath forms.